# Fail-fast iterator works not as expected

Tags: java

I have a following code and I expected to receive ConcurrentModificationException, but It works like a charm

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(3);
    for(int number : numbers) {
        if(number % 2 == 0) {
           numbers.remove((Integer)number);
        }
    }

    for(int number : numbers) {
        out.printLine(number);
    }
```

It prints 1,3. Why ?

Comment: It doesn't throw a CME in this specific case. Try changing the condition to `number % 2 == 1` and run the same code.

Comment: Right, I got CME. Could you explain me this phenomenon ?

Comment: See the duplicate for the exact same scenario.